# SQL Server Management Studio Configuration Manager Not Showing

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have seen almost every youtube video and also searched on Google but cant find a SOLUTION.

I have SQL Server Management Studio 18.4 installed and I cant find its Configuration Manager and in Services.msc I cant find its services.

EDIT: Thanks for all the support and answers, I got the solution

Comment: SQL Server **Management Studio** is just the GUI frontend tool - it's ***NOT*** the actual **core SQL Server database** - and only the actual database install will have a Configuration Manager

Comment: befor sql server 2016 all of sql server tools installed with one setup but after 2016 version the main service and management studio have two different setup and configuratopn manager install with main sql server service setup

Comment: better state your goal, what you're trying to achieve rather some settings you are not getting. It will help others to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

The Configuration Manager is a Microsoft Management Console Plug-in. To start it, run `mmc.exe`, click "Add or Remove Snap-ins", select "SQL Server Configuration manager", click "Add", and OK.

Don't forget to save the MMC configuration.

[Instructions with images are here](https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/where-is-sql-server-configuration-manager). I just looked it up recently ;)

Be aware that if you have several versions of SQL Server installed, selecting the "correct" (i.e. most recent) one, seems to be a matter of good luck.